# indexPath não corresponde ao conteúdo na tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Estou carregando um `tableView` a partir de um `array` carregado de `arrays`, todo esse processo de carregar  está funcionado perfeitamente, no entanto, quando atualizo o `tableView` (`reloadData`) com as mesmas informações e estou com o scroll na metade da lista, por exemplo, os index's se perdem, isto é, quando acesso uma célula, ele carrega informação de outra. Por outro lado, se o Scroll está no topo da `tableView`, mesmo atualizando, esse problema não ocorre. Segue código:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell_aux";

    clsTableViewCell *cell = (clsTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cell_aux" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (clsTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]                  componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

    [arInfosAll addObject:arInfos];

    NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arInfos objectAtIndex:4]];

    UIImage *Noimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"];
    cell.img.image = Noimg;


    cell.lblNome.text = [arInfos objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.lblEndereco.text =[arInfos objectAtIndex:2];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                                   NSData *imgData,
                                                   NSError * error)
        {
                                   if (!error)
                                   {
                                       UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                                       cell.img.image = img;
                                   }

                               }];
        }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Por que você está fazendo isso `[arInfosAll addObject:arInfos];`? Mais uma dúvida, por que você não usa NSDictionary para cada indice de sua array ao invés de outra array?

Comment: Na verdade poderia usar o NSDictionary de fato, mas acabei carregando em um array, pois o conteúdo que o preenche, era uma string delimitada por "|" pipes, então utilizei arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arrayAux objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]                  componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]]; A Utilização [arInfosAll addObject:arInfos] é para guardar cada array, pois utilizarei mais a frente. Mas isso pode influenciar nesse problema que estou enfrentando?

Comment: Um dos seus problemas eh q arInfos  eh uma ivar. experimente definir e alocar ela dentro do cellForRowAtIndexPath. ou seja, troque o arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  por  NSArray *arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: Olá, Muito obrigado pelo retorno! Fiz as alterações recomendadas, mas se acho que deve haver algum outro problema, pois ainda não funcionou, infelizmente. Também fiz um teste sem "sendAsynchronousRequest" e o problema persistiu.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema que você está tendo é por conta do:
    arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Você aponta o arInfos para um array e depois adiciona ele ao arInfosAll
O problema eh q na outra interação o arInfos passa a apontar para outro array, então acaba que o arInfosAll fica apontado para varios arrays iguais (o último a ser atribuido ao ArInfos)

troque

```
arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

por

```
NSArray *arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Olá, Muito obrigado pelo retorno! Fiz as alterações recomendadas, mas se acho que deve haver algum outro problema, pois ainda não funcionou, infelizmente. Também fiz um teste sem "sendAsynchronousRequest" e o problema persistiu.